# How do I prove these functions are linear independent?

Tags: linear-algebra, functions

So i need to determine if these functions are linear dependent or independent:  $$f_1(x)= \ln(\sqrt{x^2+1}+x)\\f_2(x)= \ln(\sqrt{x^2+1}-x) $$ 
I cant find the way to resolve this, can anyone help me? Thank you

Comment: Hint: a pair of vectors is linearly dependent if one of them is a scalar multiple of the other.

Comment: Yes, fixed. Thanks.

Comment: Observe that $f_1(x)+f_2(x)=0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$f_1 (x)=\ln (\sqrt {x^2+1}+x) $$

then multiplying by the conjugate, we get

$$f_1 (x)=\ln (\frac {x^2+1-x^2}{\sqrt {x^2+1}-x} )$$

$$=\ln (\frac {1}{f_2 (x)} )$$
$$=-f_2 (x) .$$

what is your conclusion ?.

Comment: they are opposite thus they are linear independent?

Comment: @NicolasGallardo No, there is a relation between f_1 and f_2 which is $f_1+f_2=0$ so they are linear DEPENDENT.

Comment: @NicolasGallardo Independant means no relation.

Answer (score 0):

HINT: solve the equation
$$\alpha\ln(\sqrt {x^2+1}+x)+\beta\ln(\sqrt{x^2+1}-x)=0$$ for all real $x$